# iphone app : EXC_BAD_ACCESS, message sent to deallocated instance

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I am a new iPhone developer. I am working on an application which used two table views.
    My code was working fine with iOS 6, but when I went to iOS 7, and tried to launch the application I get into below error.
    Based on some answers present over the net, I Enable Zombie.
    The initial error message that was returned was **EXC_BAD_ACCESS**. When I enabled NSZombieEnabled I got the error message **"-[CFString retain]: message sent to deallocated instance"**

Here is the piece of code, throwing error,
    The causing the error is,

`SystemViewController.h`

```
if(indexPath.section == 0)
{
  //User Info section
  if(indexPath.row == 0)
  {
    cell2.label1.text = @"User";
    cell2.label2.text = [UserInfoBean userName];
  }
  else
  {
   cell2.label1.text = @"SI Host URL";
   cell2.label2.text = [UserInfoBean url];
  }
  cell = cell2;
}

Interface UserInfoBean.h

@implementation UserInfoBean

static NSString *userName;
static NSString *url;
static NSString *presentNode;




+ (NSString *)userName { return userName; }
+ (NSString *)url { return url; }
+ (NSString *)presentNode { return presentNode; }


+ (void)setUserName:(NSString *)newVar { userName = newVar; }
+ (void)setUrl:(NSString *)newVar { url = newVar; }
+ (void)setPresentNode:(NSString *)newVar { presentNode = newVar; }

@end

Thanks in advance!
```

Comment: Here is the UserInfoBean class,

Comment: where is your UserInfoBean class? crosscheck your UserInfoBean class property geter and setter method implementations (expcly userName, url).

Comment: Interface UserInfoBean.h

@interface UserInfoBean : NSObject { 
}


+ (NSString *)userName;
+ (NSString *)url;
+ (NSString *)presentNode;


+ (void)setUserName:(NSString *)newVa;
+ (void)setUrl:(NSString *)newVa;
+ (void)setPresentNode:(NSString *)newVa;

Comment: please use the default property declration. ex: @property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *userName;

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using properties instead of writing your own variable accessor methods, like this:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *userName;
```

The compiler takes care of all the setting/getting those variables, and using *retain* will do the following:

> Retaining an object creates a strong reference, and an object cannot
>   be deallocated until all of its strong references are released. If two
>   objects retain each other, neither object ever gets deallocated
>   because the connection between them cannot be broken

Once you create the property, you can remove the getter/setter methods and simply use UserInfoBean.userName = @"something" to set or NSString *something = UserInfoBean.userName to get.